# Understanding Serre's Criterion for affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Stack's Project, Lemma.30.3.1 (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XF) and stuck at understanding some statements :

[image]

[image]

**Q.1)** For the first underlined statement, what does "In fact, the restriction of $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I'}$ to $U$ corrresponds to the $A$-module $A/\mathfrak{m}$" exactly means? And why $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I'}) = A/\mathfrak{m}$ is true?

**Q.2)** And for the second underlined statement, why each subquotient $\mathcal{F}_i/\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$ is isomorphic to a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer of Q.1)**

For a closed subset $Y\subseteq X$, the reduced closed subscheme structure $\iota: Y\hookrightarrow X$ is defined in such a way that (c.f. proof of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01J3 ) if $\mathcal{I}$ denotes its (quasi coherent) sheaf of ideals, we have for every affine open $V\subseteq X$ that $\mathcal{I}(V)\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X(V)$ is the radical ideal such that $V\cap Y=\mathcal{V}(\mathcal{I}(V))$.

Hence as $U\cap Z=\emptyset$ we have $\mathcal{I}(U)=A$, and as $U\cap Z'=\{x\}$ we have $\mathcal{I'}(U)=\mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq A$ is the maximal ideal with $\mathcal{V}(\mathfrak{m})=\overline{\{x\}} = \{x\}$. (c.f. Use the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Proposition 2.3). Now notice that restriction to $U$ is exact: indeed, exactness can be checked on stalks, and we have $\mathcal{F}_P=(\mathcal{F}|_U)_P$ for all $P\in U$. Thus we obtain the SES
$$
0\to \mathcal{I}'|_U\to\mathcal{I}|_U\to(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}')|_U\to 0
$$
of quasi-coherent sheaves on $U$. As $U$ is affine and everything is quasi-coherent, taking global sections is exact (cf Hartshorne Proposition II.5.6), so we obtain that $(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}')(U)\cong A/\mathfrak{m}$. By (Hartshorne's) definition of being quasi-coherent, as $U$ is affine, we have $(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}')|_U\cong (A/\mathfrak{m})^{\sim}$, where $(\bullet)^{\sim}:\text{Mod}_A\to\text{QCoh}_U$ is the usual equivalence of categories. This is what is meant by "the restriction of $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ to $U$ corresponds to the $A$-module $A/\mathfrak{m}$".

Now as stated in the text, $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ is supported at $x$. Indeed, notice that if $\iota: Y\hookrightarrow X$ is a closed subscheme with sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{J}$, and if $V\subseteq X$ is an open subset, then $\mathcal{J}|_V$ is the sheaf of ideals of $\iota_V:Y\cap V\hookrightarrow V$. Indeed, denote by $j$ resp. $j_Y$ the inclusion of $V$ into $X$ resp. of $V\cap Y$ into $Y$, so that $\iota\circ j_Y=j\circ\iota_V$. Then if $V’\subseteq V$ is open, $j^{\#}(V’)$ and $j_Y^{\#}(V’\cap Y)$ are just the identity map, so that
$$
\mathcal{J}(V’)=\ker \iota^{\#}(V’)=\ker\iota_V^{\#}(V’).
$$
This implies that $\mathcal{J}|_V$ is the ideal sheaf of $V\cap Y$. So if $V:=X\setminus\{x\}$, and as $Z\cap V=Z'\cap V$ both carry the (unique) reduced closed subscheme structure, we obtain $\mathcal{I}|_V=\mathcal{I}'|_V$, and thus $\mathcal{I}_P=\mathcal{I}'_P$ for all $P\in V$, i.e. $P\neq x$. So by taking stalks in the SES
$$
0\to \mathcal{I}'\to\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'\to 0
$$
we obtain indeed that $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ is supported at $x$.

Therefore, $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ is in fact the skyscraper sheaf associated to $(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}')_x$. To see this, note that for any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ and any point $P$ we have a canonical map $\mathcal{F}\to i_P(\mathcal{F}_P)$, where $i_P(\bullet)$ denotes the skyscraper sheaf associated to the Abelian group $\bullet$; the map is defined by sending $s\in\mathcal{F}(V)$ to $s_P\in i_P(\mathcal{F}_P)(V)=\mathcal{F}_P$ if $P\in V$, and to $0$ otherwise. Applying this for $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ and $P=x$, we obtain a map $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'\to i_x((\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}')_x)$. This is in fact an isomorphism, as can be checked by taking stalks on both sides.

Hence, as we know the value of $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ at $U$ (which contains $x$), namely $A/\mathfrak{m}$, we obtain $(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}')(X)=(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}')(U)\cong A/\mathfrak{m}$.

**Answer of Q.2)**
It follows from the construction they give right afterwards: $\mathcal{F}_i:=\mathcal{F}\cap (\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus i}\oplus 0^{\oplus n-i})$. More precisely, $\mathcal{F}_i$ is the kernel of the inclusion $\iota:\mathcal{F}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}$ composed with the projection $p_i:\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}\to\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n-i}$ onto the last $n-i$ components, so in particular it is quasi-coherent. Also, we see that $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}\subseteq\mathcal{F}_i$, as $p_i$ can be obtained from $p_{i-1}$ by post-composing with projection to the last $n-i$ components of $\mathcal{O}_X^{n-(i-1)}$. Now let us check that $\mathcal{F}_i/\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$ injects into $\mathcal{O}_X$. Let $\pi_i:\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}\to\mathcal{O}_X$ be the projection onto the $i$-th component. Now a section $s\in\mathcal{F}_i(V)$ is mapped to $0$ by $\pi_i$ if and only if it is mapped to $0$ by $p_{i-1}$, because the last $n-i$ components of $s$ are already $0$. Hence the kernel of $\pi_i|_{\mathcal{F}_i}$ is precisely $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$, and thus by the first isomorphism theorem we obtain an injective morphism $\mathcal{F}_i/\mathcal{F}_{i-1}\to\mathcal{O}_X$, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask question further? 1) How can we prove that $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ is supported at x? I stuck at showing that $\mathcal{I}_y = \mathcal{I'}_y$ for all $y\neq x$. 2) The canonical map $\mathcal{F} \to \prod_{P \in X} i_P(\mathcal{F}_P)$ is an isomorphism? Where can I find an associated proof?

Comment: I added explanations, and simplified your arguments when I felt you were overcomplicating things. Let me know if there is still something unclear.

Comment: For the SES : $0\to\mathcal{J}\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y\to 0$ to $V$ in showing $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}'$ is supported at $x$, perhaps,  ($\iota_{Y,*}\mathcal{O}_Y)|_V = \iota_{Y\cap V, *}\mathcal{O}_{Y\cap V}$? And for the Answer of Q.2), as the first isomorphism theorem, in which category is the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: O.K. I figured out what the first isomorphism theroem means. So it's o.k. if you answer my first question in comment. :)

Comment: @Plantation I added an explanation, I hope it’s clear now. You are right about $(\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y)|_V=\iota_{V,*}\mathcal{O}_{Y\cap V}$, but I think it’s the most straightforward to argue as I did in the post.

Comment: O.K. I'll try to check it. Thanks for kind explanation ~!